# Binding multiple Events - Javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Is there something wrong with my syntax? The first event was working fine until I started adding multiple events. Now, no event tracking seems to be working at all.

I've checked for any typo's etc.

```
$('#GetBusinessHelp').bind('click', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'Get Business Help');
});

$('#EmailMailTo').bind('click', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'tab', 'click', 'Mailto');
});
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than that. What exactly 'is not working'? What's "ga()"?

Comment: do you get any errors? if so what is the error. The error is most likely not related to the posted script assuming ga() works correctly

Comment: in terms of google analytics I've used mousedown instead of click because it registers before click but unless you show us where ga is defined - nobody can help you based on what you have so far

Comment: Your syntax looks good, and the events should fire correctly.  Have you confirmed the click events are being fired correctly?  Try commenting out the _ga_ function calls and adding an alert.  I'm thinking the issue might lie in the _ga_ function

Comment: I just realised that I was looking at the wrong tab. The event tracking is actually working fine, so i think i'll delete this question. Sorry for wasting your time. but out of interest, why do you choose to use MouseDown? I don't understand the significance?

Comment: mousedown registers before click in the DOM I believe; it's a work around where GA didn't register clicks because the link was external and maybe didn't call the function in time - most of the time it works with click though

Answer (score 1):

Refer the API doc for binding multiple events : http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Multiple event types can be bound at once by including each one separated by a space as given below.

```
  $('#foo').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('entered');
    });
```

Here you have bind only click event.
Other events will be bind with click only using space.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that I was looking at the wrong tab. The event tracking is actually working fine, so i think i'll delete this question. Sorry for wasting your time